# JQuery Class selector not working on Zoom plugin

Tags: jquery-selectors, undefined-reference

I've been trying to get jQuery to select a particular element in the JQuery zoom plugin but it doesnt seem to be working
This is the html markup for the zoom region

```
<div class="zoom" style="width: 60% !important; display: block; position: fixed; overflow: hidden;">    
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0456/6809/t/3/assets/bx_loader.gif?27021" alt="" class="abs-center-translate loader">
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0456/6809/products/568A.jpeg?v=1413437903" class="zoomImg" style="position: absolute; top: -1385.54456824513px; left: -389.68108776267px; opacity: 1; width: 682.5px; height: 1024px; border: none; max-width: none; max-height: none;">
</div>


function showZoomImgSmaller(img) {
    var zoomsmall = $('.zoom');
    zoomsmall.empty();

    zoomsmall.append('{{ "bx_loader.gif" | asset_url | img_tag: "", "abs-center-translate loader" }}');
    $('.collectionZoomContainer').show();
    zoomsmall.attr( "style","width:60%!important" );
    var zoomsmallimg= $('.zoom > img');
    console.log(zoomsmallimg.next().get());

    $('.zoomImg').attr("style","max-width:500px!important");
    zoomsmall.show();
    zoomsmall.zoom({url: img, magnify: 0.5});
  }
```

The console returns just a [] for the .zoomImg.get() and an undefined for a .zoomImg.html()

I want to change the css of this particular element and can only do it through jquery.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This works for me: `<div class="zoom" style="width: 60% !important; display: block; position: fixed; overflow: hidden;">    
</div>
function showZoomImgSmaller(img) {
    var zoomsmall = $('.zoom');
    console.log(zoomsmall);
  }

showZoomImgSmaller('');`

Comment: Yes the zoom div works. But the img tag inside it returns an undefined as mentioned. I would like to select the second image inside the div (.zoomImg) so I can change its height dynamically.Thanks for replying

Comment: `zoomsmall.empty();` is removing the child elements of your div so by the time you call `$('.zoomImg')` the only DOM in the div is the one you are adding with your append call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so I managed to get my style applied by appending css in the head of the page. This style was applied even though the element didnt exist till later. 
This is the code I used.

```
$("<style type='text/css'> .zoomImg{ max-width:200px!important;} </style>").appendTo("head");
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on here that I cannot see, but my guess is that when you call empty() on your div, you are removing all children of the div (including the .zoomImg class which you are trying to look up later). Instead of removing all elements, you might just want to remove the first image:

```
function showZoomImgSmaller(img) {
    var zoomsmall = $('.zoom');
    $('.zoom > .loader').remove(); //change is here

    zoomsmall.append('{{ "bx_loader.gif" | asset_url | img_tag: "", "abs-center-translate loader" }}'); //angular? not sure what this does
    $('.collectionZoomContainer').show(); //not sure what this
    zoomsmall.attr( "style","width:60%!important" );
    var zoomsmallimg= $('.zoom > img');
    console.log(zoomsmallimg.next().get());

    $('.zoomImg').attr("style","max-width:500px!important");
    zoomsmall.show();
    zoomsmall.zoom({url: img, magnify: 0.5});
  }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. But this this isn't working. So basically  the mark up is for the jquery zoom plugin in a modal box. I think that the Jquery Zoom is dynamically over riding the CSS for the zoomImg. Any way to test if jquery is applying my styles.  Also when I target all img tags within the .zoom class it applies the styles to the loader images but not the .zoomImg. Any help is appreciated.